# Stop playing iframe video after closing modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I need stop video from playing after closing modal window. This is my code:

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="mkdf-elements-holder-item-content mkdf-elements-holder-custom-184744" style="padding: 300px 0 200px 0">


  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
      <header style="background-color:white;" class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.visibility='hidden'"
        class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <h2 style="background-color:white; color: white"> V </h2>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
    <iframe id="ifr" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZrXbX8cWrvQ" allowscriptaccess="always"> /iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried this code, but it does not work:

```
<script>
 $("#id01").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#id03 iframe").attr("src", $("#id03 iframe").attr("src"));
    });
</script>
```

Anyone know how I can achieve to stop playing video when I close modal window?

Comment: try this: $('.videoModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {    
    var $if = $(e.delegateTarget).find('iframe');
    var src = $if.attr("src");
    $if.attr("src", '/empty.html');
    $if.attr("src", src);
});

Comment: Thank you but it stil does not work.

Comment: btw i don't see `id03` in your code isn't it be either `#id01` or `ifr`?

Comment: I tried also ifr and id01, but still nothing

Comment: Please explain your code a bit and describe what is currently happening.

Comment: When you click on div "mkdf-elements-holder-item-content mkdf-elements-holder-custom-184744", modal window with video appears. But when I close this modal window with "x", the video continues to play in the background.

Answer (score 0):

How should jQuery reference and id that is not present in your HTML? `#id03` is not existing as pointed out by @Manjuboyz, use `#ifr` instead for referencing your iframe.

```
<script>
$("#id01").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#ifr").attr("src", $("#ifr").attr("src"));
});
</script>
```

Your approach would require a reload of the entire video. If you have an iframe that contains a `<video></video>` element, you can just stop it and set it to the beginning:

```
$('#ifr').contents().find('video').each(function () {
 this.currentTime = 0; // set to beginning
 this.pause(); // set video to paused
});
```

You need to use jQuery's `contents()` to work on the DOM of the iframe.